# Fullcalendar load events from dymanic JSON

Tags: php, mysql, fullcalendar

I'm trying to load events to FullCalendar from dynamic JSON in `get-events.php`.
In `get-events.php` there is a line to load content from static JSON:

```
$json = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../json/events.json');
$input_arrays = json_decode($json, true);
```

However, my JSON file is generated from a MySQL database and that doesn't work.

All I need is speed up FullCalendar. I have huge event base up to 10 000 events starting from 2013 until today, and it's very slow when FullCalendar get only one month from all this base.
Any idea how to load events using `startParm` and `endParm` by `POST`?

Comment: You could build up an array in php to match the format needed for full calendar, then json_encode the array before passing back to full calendar.

Comment: ok done, but my JSON render about 10000 events. I only need to load the events between start and end date. How to do that in Fullcalendar v2 ? any example?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution on Chinese website :)

> file_get_contents doesn't parse the php file. It will output the programmcode in this case. Add this function to your get-events.php

```
function loadPhpFile($file) {
ob_start(); 
include $file;
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
return $content;
}
```

And then replace

```
$json = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../json/events.json');
```

with

```
$json = loadPhpFile(dirname(__FILE__) . '/db-connect.php');
```